# How to convert .JKS to "keystore" format?

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine

Two years ago I made a game in the game engine "Construct 3" there and created a key for the Play Market with the format "jks".

Now I have made an update in the game on Unity, but a key with the "keystore" format is needed there and, accordingly, I cannot download the update.

Can you please tell me how to change the file format from "jks" to "keystore"?

I tried to change it via cmd, but I got this error, although the password is correct: "keytool error: java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format"

I also tried to rename the file format, but unity writes: Cannot load keys. Make sure keystore password is incorrect.

---

I did it myself. Maybe it'll help.
The conversion from (.JKS) to (.PKCS12) helped me:

```
cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20\bin

keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore C:\Keys\keystore.jks -srcstoretype JKS -destkeystore C:\Keys\1.p12 -deststoretype PKCS12
```

And then from PKCS 12 format to JKS format (.keystore):

```
cd C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20\bin
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore C:\Keys\1.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore C:\Keys\1.keystore -deststoretype JKS
```

After that, the unity manager read keystore/

Comment: You may want to add this solution as an answer, rather than editing the question.  One thing to note is that after Java 9, the default keystore format is PKCS#12, rather than JKS (cf. https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/9-relnotes.html#JDK-8044445)